# stanford-core-nlp gem / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnnotationBridge

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stanford-nlp

I want to use the [`stanford-core-nlp` gem](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) in a rails application.

So, I followed the README file instructions:

- I installed the `stanford-core-nlp` gem and put it in the Gemfile
- I downloaded and put the contents of Stanford CoreNLP version 3.5.0 in the `bin/` folder of the gem
- I downloaded and put the contents of the full Stanford Tagger version 3.5.0 in the `bin/taggers/` folder of the gem
- I downloaded and put the `bridge.jar` file in the `bin/` folder of the gem

But when I want to use the gem and write in a rails controller file:
`pipeline = StanfordCoreNLP.load(:pos)`

I have this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnnotationBridge

But I can see the `AnnotationBridge.java` file in the `bin/` folder of the gem...

I don't know how or where I can specify the path...

Any help?

Comment: The ClassNotFoundException usually indicates that the class is not on the classpath.  If you have a .java file, you need to compile it to a .class file and ensure that the .class file is on the classpath.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried to compile the .java file with this command line `javac -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar AnnotationBridge.java` but 1 error remains :
`AnnotationBridge.java:14: error: method get in class ArrayCoreMap cannot be applied to given types;`
`Object object = ((ArrayCoreMap) entity).get(klass);`
`required: Class<? extends Key<VALUE>>`
`found: Class<CoreAnnotation>`
Do you have an idea?